# Can I use electric tape instead of soldering for Speakers?

Tags: soldering, speakers, sound

I want to get a [3W 4Ohms Speaker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CHYIU26) for a bluetooth speaker project that I'm doing, but the speakers require me to solder wires onto them, while I don't have any experience in soldering. Am I able to use Electric Tape as a substitute, or are there any better substitutes, if any, that I can use?

Comment: "electric tape": this sounds like it's the *insulating* electrical tape? That's pretty much the opposite of creating a solid, conductive connection.

Comment: Soldering is a « basic » skill that you should master and this sounds like a good opportunity to practise - low power, easy access, not too small, so take the chance to improve your skills.

Comment: Do the tight wire wrap. It's even better than soldering. But unfortunately there is no wire coming out from speakers to wrap it, so get the soldering iron.

Answer (score 3):

Get a soldering iron already!  Or if this is really the only time you would ever use it, have someone with a soldering iron solder the wires for you as a favor.  With the right equipment, it should only take a minute or two.

You are also confusing means of making a connection with the means of holding that connection in place.  Solder does both these things.  Electrical tape only does the latter.  Therefore, no, electrical tape is not a substitute for soldering.

### Not recommended

You can strip maybe ½ to ¾ inch of insulation from each wire end.  Then run each wire thru the eyelet hole in the speaker lug, then twist it tightly around itself.  The twisting will tend to keep the wire in place, but it still won't make a great contact.

After you've done the best you can to electrically connect the wires with the speaker eyelets and to keep them there, you can wrap each connection in electrical tape.  That will protect the bare area from unintended electrical contact, and will help stabilize the kludgy joint mechanically.

While the above will largely work if done right, when the speaker is powered you can probably hear little crackling sounds as you pull on the wires or flex them around near the speaker.  Again, not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Yes wrap and tape wire connections are old as dirt.

The key though is to ensure the wire makes a good mechanical connection. If the connection tab on the speaker has a wire-hole in it, strip enough of the end of the wire to let you poke it through then bend it back on itself so you can twist the wire back on itself.

The goal is to make that mechanical connection strong enough so the wire does not move on the tab when you wiggle it. (And in this case, obviously, when the speaker vibrates!)

When you are happy with it, tape it up.

Note: The connection will never withstand much pulling on the wire. Tying the cable down somewhere with a tie-wrap to prevent pulling on those joins is a good idea.

**Add:** If you have or can buy some heat shrink tubing that will work better than tape. The shrink action adds compression to the join making it stronger. If you use an inch or so it will also add considerable strain relief to the joint.

Comment: wire wrap works best with tinned solid core wire so that the wire surface matches the terminal surface.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably fit a screw terminal strip to the speaker lugs.

[image: scre terminal strips]  [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MFEOTSW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MFEOTSW)

these strips can be separated into individual wire connectors using a knife, so chop of two pieces and connect the wire using one screw and the speaker using the other.

ypu may need to trim the plastic back a bit at the speaker end of the connector.

Answer (score 0):

No, electrical tape as far as I know it is an *insulator*, the **opposite** of what you want to have when you connect two cables.

Frankly, soldering wires together is pretty easy. I don't really see any alternative connection technology than soldering here.

Comment: I meant the electric tape holds the wire in place.

Comment: well, as Trevor said in his answer: that does work, electrically, but it's flimsy (as it doesn't withstand any pull) and usually, it's harder to even do well than just going ahead and soldering a cable to a speaker terminal.